# Dado "... existe un tipo de sordera (...). Se *le* conoce como X", ¿podríamos decir "se *lo* conoce"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-directos, clíticos

He visto esta cita:

> En Costa Rica existe un tipo de sordera única en el mundo. **Se le conoce** como la “Sordera de los Monge”.

Me pregunto si es posible escribir la segunda oración así:

> **Se lo conoce** como la “Sordera de los Monge”.

Para mí la segunda forma tiene más sentido, dado que:

> *Conocen el tipo de sordera* como la “Sordera de los Monge”.
>   → *Lo conocen* como la “Sordera de los Monge”.
>   → *Se lo conoce* como la “Sordera de los Monge”.

Es decir, entiendo que se puede reemplazar 'lo' por 'la' si nos referimos directamente a "la sordera" y no a "el tipo de sordera".

Comment: Veo dos opciones "Se **lo** conoce coma **la** Sordera..." o "Se **lo** conoce como l̶a̶  Sordera..."

Answer (score 4):

«Se le conoce como la “sordera de los Monge”» es [leísmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo) (*le* es pronombre [dativo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caso_dativo) y en este caso corresponde acusativo, porque la sordera o el tipo de sordera en cuestión son objeto directo del verbo *conocer*).

«Se la conoce como la “sordera de los Monge”» es correcto y la forma más común. Aunque en la oración anterior se hable de un tipo de sordera, «un tipo de» funciona como un simple modificador. Creo que algo similar pasa cuando dudamos del número con que debemos referirnos a «un grupo de personas» (¿decimos «un grupo de personas me esperaba» o «un grupo de personas me esperaba**n**»?).

«Se lo conoce como la “sordera de los Monge”» también es correcto, si antes hablábamos de «un tipo de sordera», pero por alguna razón no suena del todo bien. Sonaría bien sólo si volviéramos a mencionar explícitamente el referente, diciendo: «A este tipo de sordera se lo conoce como…».

Comment: Me sigue sonando mejor "se **la** conoce", precisamente por lo que has dicho: un tipo de es una locución que actúa como modificador.